# Assign all permissions to a user programatically

Tags: users, testing

Is there a way to assign all the permissions to an authenticated user through code, I want to do it in unit tests.

Comment: I'm not a testing expert, but can't you run the test as user 1?

Comment: No, as i see when the unit tests run, there are only two roles (authenticated role and anonymous role), no administrator role exists, so i would need to assign permissions to the authenticated user, or might need to create a administrator role programatically which is even more difficult for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use rules - when a user is created (could include certain contextual requirements) then all the roles are added.

or the less tidy way

You could get all the roles from the DB and then insert each into the user_roles table.

Something like:

```
$userID = 'ENTER UID';
$query = db_select('user_roles', 'r')->fields('r')->execute();

while($role = $query->fetchObject()){
    db_insert('user_roles')->fields(array('uid' => $userID, 'rid' => $role->rid))->execute();
}
drupal_static_reset('user_access');  /* Flush the caches */
drupal_static_reset('user_role_permissions');  /* Flush the caches */
```

The code is untested but should be a good foundation.

You can also do the same in Drupal by loading the user object and making the changes, but the above will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this helps answer your question:

You could add permissions to an user using this code

> `$this->drupalCreateUser(array('access content', 'create page content'));`

Here is [a link](http://drupal.org/node/478520) for more information on this subject.

Comment: It would be very much appreciated if you post the relevant parts of the solution over here. That way, your answer can stand alone (with the link pointing to in-depth information and acting as a attribution).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your scenario, I think that you can review this way to create a role with permissions http://drupal.org/node/271234#comment-3381548 (I think that this way is easy to understand and test). Then assign the user to the role:

http://mattdanger.net/2009/12/programmatically-create-users-in-drupal-6-x/

http://grahammickle.com/blog/php/assign-user-role-programmatically

http://drupal.org/node/28379

Comment: what i m trying to do is to assign all the available permissions to a single role and assign that role to my user, figuring out the best possibility to that, what i want is an administrator role, but administrator role is not available in running unit tests